# Converting values of dictionary to the timestamp format

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary, timestamp, type-conversion

I have the dictionary like this:

```
>>print xdict 
{'time': [(2015, 6, 3, 10, 41, 3), (2015, 6, 3, 20, 32, 21), ..., ...]}
```

Is it a way to transform those values to timestamp format? I wanted to be exactly like  this:

```
print xdict
{'time': [1433320863.0, 1433356341.0, ..., ...]}
```

Comment: I tried several things with converting using datetime but still not getting what I want at the end.;/

Comment: Yes, it is possible to perform that computation.  Show the code that you have tried so that we can explain why it did not work and correct it.

Comment: @Kyll: the question is obviously is not too broad. It has concise answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your time tuples do not represent time in UTC. If it is your local timezone and the utc offset rules for the corresponding times are the same as they are now or if C time library has access to a historical time zone database on your platform then you could pass the time tuples to `time.mktime()` to get "seconds since epoch":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time

x = {'time': [(2015, 6, 3, 10, 41, 3), (2015, 6, 3, 20, 32, 21)]}
x['time'] = [time.mktime(tt + (-1,)*3) for tt in x['time']]
```

Otherwise, you should use `pytz` to get access to the tz database on all platforms and compute the correct "seconds since the Epoch" (POSIX timestamp) corresponding to the input time tuples:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime
import pytz # $ pip install pytz
import tzlocal # $ pip install tzlocal

local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone() # pytz tzinfo representing local time
epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
x = {'time': [(2015, 6, 3, 10, 41, 3), (2015, 6, 3, 20, 32, 21)]}
x['time'] = [(local_timezone.localize(datetime(*tt), is_dst=None) - epoch).total_seconds()
             for tt in x['time']]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and contributing to Stack Overflow, however please take a second look at the question, for it seems to be off-topic according to the [help/on-topic]. Answering off-topic question make it look like it's okay to ask such questions - it's not. Off-topic questions might get closed and then deleted, which would nullify your contribution!

Comment: @ J.F. Sebastian Thank you for your answer but could you explain me more this line? time.mktime(tt + (-1,)*3) ... ?

Comment: @Kyll: I don't consider this question to be off-topic. I would appropriate if you don't post template comments and provide reasons that are specific to this question.

Comment: @MateuszMateja: try the parts in Python REPL e.g., `(-1,)*3 == (-1, -1, -1)` and `tt + (-1,)*3 == (2015, 6, 3, 10, 41, 3, -1, -1, -1)`

Comment: @ J.F. Sebastian Thank you very much for deeply answering my question. Now I can apply it also for other things. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the list and excute the code below. You need `time.mktime` in order to change into seconds

```
import time
import datetime

a = (2015, 6, 3, 10, 41, 3)

b = datetime.datetime.strptime(', '.join(str(x) for x in a),'%Y, %m, %d, %H, %M, %S')

print(time.mktime(b.timetuple()))

>>> 1433342463.0
```

Comment: The tuple can be unpacked into the datetime initialiser.

Answer (score -2):

Initialize datetime.datetime with unpacked tuple(over * operator).
Then using map and lambda you can easily get your goal.

```
import time
import datetime

def transform(xdict):
  return {"time": map(lambda k: time.mktime(datetime.datetime(*k).timetuple()), xdict["time"])}
```

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". There are lots of examples of such poor answers; but you don't want to be one of those people, right?

Comment: Thank you very very much! ;)

Comment: This answer is what I was looking for - exact solving my question so I think discouraging such answers is more bad. Cheers for @Radek Luner!

Comment: @Mogsdad: an explanation would certanly make the answer better but there is no need to downvote it (the code works (in many cases)).

Comment: you don't need to use `datetime` here, you could [pass the time tuple to `mktime()` directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33044664/4279). `mktime()` may be wrong on some platforms for dates from the past/future if the utc offset rules may change in the local timezone.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Your assumption that I down-voted the answer is unwarranted, and as it happens incorrect.

Comment: @Mogsdad: it doesn't matter whether you personally did it. You've encouraged it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - I encouraged a new user to write a more complete answer that would benefit more people.